Does SE's intolerance of opinion result in McNamara Fallacy?
Recently, two SE questions have been closed (or recommended they be closed) because they “could be answered by opinions”.
I understand (and whole heartedly agree) that SE wants answers supported by evidence. But to assume that all opinions could not be supported by evidence amounts to zealotry.
Banning a question because it may be answered with unsupported opinions is a logical generalization fallacy along the line of “The Beatles are musicians. They are all Englishmen. So all Englishmen are musicians”.
Over-reliance on factual evidence like “hard data” can result in the McNamara fallacy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNamara_fallacy

… when the McNamara discipline is applied too literally, the first
step is to measure whatever can be easily measured. The second step is
to disregard that which can't easily be measured or given a
quantitative value. The third step is to presume that what can't be
measured easily really isn't important.
…General Edward Lansdale reportedly told McNamara, who was trying
to develop a list of metrics to allow him to scientifically follow the
progress of the war, that he was not considering the feelings of the
common rural Vietnamese people. McNamara ... told Lansdale that he could not measure it,
so it must not be important.

I think SE would be better if it welcomed evidence-supported opinions. Participation in SE has been decreasing for years What are SE's "vital signs" . Welcoming evidence-supported opinions may make the site more attractive without turning it into another Reddit.
Our community has a mechanism for downvoting questions and answers which are unsupported by evidence. Is it really necessary to close these questions?
But then, that’s just my opinion.
EDIT 5 months later: Its still going on. Recently several questions have been flagged for removal because they "may be" answered by opinions. If opinions which are unsupported by evidence are submitted, by all means downvote or delete. But don't delete the question. That just prevents evidence-supported answers from being submitted.

can you drop links to the two specific ones you are talking baout

uhoh! more "factual evidence" supporting Godwin's law (humor)

The "opinion-based" close reason is not so much that a question could be answered by opinions, but that there could be multiple answers all with different opinions, which doesn't fit the SE model of providing an accurate answer to a question for future visitors to refer to. And that is pretty much hard coded by Stack Exchange themselves - and I don't think you'll change the company's mind.
That said, some sites are very strict in requiring citations/evidence. Some are very subjective. Space Exploration Stack Exchange is in between. You'll see there are answers with mathematic or physics detail, and others which amount to "I have seen this" so the line is not very precise between what makes good answers and what doesn't here.
Anyone with privileges is allowed to vote to close, but remember it is just a vote. It requires a few more folks to agree, and in the mean time, this community is pretty good at adding comments to try and guide the asker to edit a question to better fit.
There is also no concept of "banning" a question. Even if a question is closed it can be discussed and reopened, as happens regularly.

I think @RoryAlsop's answer nails it.
I understand the frustration felt when votes to close a question for this reason are cast. I often feel it's a self-fulfilling prophecy; "Of course no fact-based answers can be posted if you block all further answers from being posted - why not leave it open for a while first and wait and see?"
Having been here a while and seen how the community works, and having received many answers myself, I think there are plenty of examples of well-received and welcomed answers that can be described as evidence-supported opinions.
There's a large class of questions of the form "Could X work?" or "Is X a good idea?" and in their original state many need to be closed, not because they can be answered by evidence-supported opinions, but because they can be answered validly by two or more evidence-supported opinions that completely contradict each other.
In that case, the result is outside the scope of what Stack Exchange is for.
Stack Exchange is not a forum
Instead, as @RoryAlsop points out, the community often works to help the OP adjust the question form from "Would X work?" to a much better "Challenges to X?" which also accommodates informed evidence-supported opinion-based answers but in a much more useful way.
Then what often happens is that a consensus or concurrence emerges among answers, or sometimes two different but helpful ways of looking at the challenges emerge.
What I learned here is to trust the community, work to improve questions or refactor them when necessary to avoid closure or jumpstart reopening, and to, from time to time, just move on to the next question, maybe revisit the old question in six months with a fresh mind and more patience and acceptance for how other community members see things.

In response to

EDIT 5 months later: It's still going on. Recently several questions have been flagged for removal because they "may be" answered by opinions. If opinions which are unsupported by evidence are submitted, by all means downvote or delete. But don't delete the question. That just prevents evidence-supported answers from being submitted.


The applicability of the precise wording of close reasons is often imperfect, if the complaint is about the phrase "may be" then that should be taken up in the main meta (where those things are decided) and not here.
As for "Recently several questions..." which ones!? Without linking to specific examples of the questions that were closed that you feel should have remained open, how can other's appreciate what it is you'd like to see changed?
Although "answers primarily opinion-based" is (probably) my least-frequently selected close reason because I often see unexpected and surprisingly fact-based answers posted within a few days (as long as they don't get 5 close votes), the reason people that do use this option use it is to encourage an adjustment in the way the question is asked.

As an example, "When will we get to Mars?" vs "What are the show-stopper issues that must be overcome before we can get to Mars?"
